# Why is my array always nil?

Tags: swift

I really don't know whats going on and Im really confused why this happens. I might be doing something wrong but when i try to access my array out of the function, there is nothing in it. If anyone can help me please tell me.

```
import UIKit

class withFriendsView: UITableViewController {

    var withFriendsArray:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
    var friendImg = [PFFile]()
    var friendusername = [String]()
    var friendName = [String]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad() 
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        loadWithFriends()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning() 
    }



    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return friendusername.count
    }


    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell:WithFriendsCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("withFriends", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! WithFriendsCell

        friendImg[indexPath.row].getDataInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (data:NSData?, error:NSError?) -> Void in

            let img = UIImage(data: data!)

            cell.friendsImage.image = img
        }

        return cell
    }

    func loadWithFriends() {

        var channelQuery = ChannelQuery.query()!
        var activityQuery = ActivityQuery.query()!

        channelQuery.whereKey("Host", matchesKey: "ActChannel", inQuery: activityQuery)
        channelQuery.whereKey("Host", equalTo: "kia495")
        var data = channelQuery.findObjects()

        if data!.count != 0 {

        for objects in data! {

                let username = objects["Users"]!!.objectId

                let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "objectId == %@", username!!)
                var userQuery = PFQuery(className: "_User", predicate: predicate)
                var objects = userQuery.findObjects()

                for object in objects! {

                    friendImg.append(object.objectForKey("profileImage") as! PFFile)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have a bug on line 72 of your code. I can tell that because I have ESP and know what your code looks like without seeing it. Most people don't have ESP, so they won't be able to tell what's wrong. Lucky thing I read your post, huh?

Comment: sorry i accidentally posted it without the code.

Comment: Hint: What do you think what findObjects**InBackground**WithBlock does? – If you search for "return value from asynchronous method" then you should find similar questions with answers.

Comment: Ok, you posted the code. Now can you tell us what array you're talking about, where it's defined, where it gets a value assigned to it, and where you're seeing it as nil? It would also be helpful to tell us what framework you're using, and what a ChannelQuery and ActivityQuery is

Comment: there is only one array in the function -_- ! and it gives me nil everywhere i try to access it in the program.

Comment: I am trying to help you, but you need to provide enough information for your readers to be able to see what's going on. I'm done playing 20 questions with a rude first-time poster.

Comment: I dont need ur help thank you very much! Martin took care of it and he had as much information as you did !

Comment: Where are you accessing it?

Comment: Arbitur im just trying to get data and access it in cellForRow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should reload the table after adding an element to the array

First move `loadWithFriends()` from `viewDidAppear` to `viewDidLoad`

in this line, you are returning another array, try returning friendImg.count

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return friendusername.count
}
```

Comment: thank you eduardo ! I've been playing with it a lot and kind of noticed that it could be a bug ! i updated the code if it helps more. I stopped using the findinthebackground function but still not very functional. appreciate your help tho.

Comment: @KiarashTeymoury exactly which array is returning nil in which line?

Comment: When I try to get data back from FriendImg to display pictures on table nothing happens and when i mannually put a number for the number of rowws i get a crash but when its FriendImg.count its just nothing but doesnt crash. its really weird never had this problem and ive just been trying different methods thats why i have that MutableArray!

Comment: @KiarashTeymoury or change loadWithFriends() to viewDidLoad()

Comment: unfortunately, non of those methods worked however when i moved it to viewDidLoad() and did println for the Img array, i get data but it seems like once its out of the function, then it just holds no data

Comment: ok well i have an update which im just very shocked about. I finally got it to work and i just gave this function a try because i figured that its my cellforRow thats not receiving any number fro, the array. Why ? idk. this is what i did and returned and int from count object and set the function to the cellforrow and worked perfectly fine

Comment: How do you check outside the function, because the numberOfRows has this variable friendusername.count instead of friendImg.count

Comment: Well i think we just got our perfect answer i totally didnt realize i had another Array set to the numberOfRows! well i promise i tried every array but i guess it only likes to work when it feels like it. IF any of you can help me with the dispatch then i would really appreciate it, i have never really got to use that so i would like to know more about it and if it helps with running the data load faster maybe ? Thank you Eduardo

Comment: @KiarashTeymoury perfectly I just modify my answer, and about the dispatch is exactly the same, but if in a background thread you want to modify the UI, use the dispatch that will get the UI Thread

Answer (score 0):

This `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` looks like an async method, which will immediately return. The code in the block will be executed only when the data is ready. So when you try to access the data from `friendImg`, it may not be ready and you will get nil.

If the data is not very large, you can use sync method to do this.

Comment: Oh that makes sense ! the data could possible get larger as more people get added to it however i i really want to try the sync method but i cant really find anything that useful on it, can you please explain how that could be done ?

Comment: I don't think so because the method is called with viewDidLoad, and that variable should be loaded